Why does the Haar orthonormal system span the whole $L^2$?
I am reading "Real Analysis with an Introduction to Wavelets and Applications" because I want to understand wavelets better for my work. I got stuck on a detail about the Haar Basis in Chapter 7.
The paragraph begins by defining the box function
$$
B(x):= \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } x \in [0,\ 1] \\
0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases},
$$
then defines the rescalings with $(n,k) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Z}$
$$
B_{n,\ k}(x):= 2^{\frac{n}{2}} \ B(2^{n} \ x - k). 
$$
Then, it defines $V_{n}:= \text{Span}(\left\{B_{n,k}\right\}_{k \in \mathbb{Z}})$.
Clearly, $\overline{\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} V_{n}} = L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ because $\{ \varphi_{n,k}\}_{n,k}$ can approximate continuous compact support functions that are dense in $L^{2}$.
$$ V_{n} = \text{span}\left\{ B_{n,\ k} \right\}_{n,k \in  \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Z} }.$$
Then, the author defines the space $W_{0}$ as the orthogonal complement of $V_{0}$ in $V_{1}$.
Again, it is easy to verify that an orthonormal basis $\{ H_{0,k} \}$ are the integer translations of the Haar function
$$
H(x):= \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } [0,\frac{1}{2}) \\  
-1 & \text{if } [\frac{1}{2},1) \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Finally, the author defines $W_{n}$ as the orthogonal complement of $V_{n}$: $W_{n} \oplus V_{n} = V_{n+1}$.
The part I am slightly dubious about is the following:
$$ L^{2} = \bigoplus W_{n}.$$
Why is it so obvious to him? I managed to prove it but in a slightly convoluted way.
If a non-negative function $f$ tested against the Haar basis always gives zero, it means that $f$ tested against the dyadic intervals is $0$, and this implies $f=0$. If a function $f$ is continuous and non-zero, without loss of generality, there exists a point $f(x_{0}) \neq 0$. By zooming near enough to $x_{0}$, I can repeat the previous argument, obtaining the absurd $f(x_0)=0$. Thus, I have proved $\bigcap W_{n}^{\perp} \cap C(\mathbb{R}) = \{ 0\}$, and since $C(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $L^{2}$, we have $\bigcap W_{n}^{\perp} = \{ 0 \}$.
Consequently, given that $W_{n} \perp W_{n'}$ for all $n \neq n'$, we have
$$ L^{2}= \bigoplus W_{n}.$$ I was hoping there might be some more general principle I can appeal to, or by proving the following equality:
$$\bigcap_{n} W_{n}^{\perp} = \bigcap_{n} V_{n} = \{ 0 \}.$$

Hello everyone, I would greatly appreciate some feedback on my question. I'm worried it might be too complicated or lacking essential details. Thank you! This isn't the first time I've made 10 visualizations without receiving any comments, leading me to suspect there could be an issue with how I'm phrasing my questions.

$\newcommand{\pP}{P}$
$\newcommand{\ds}{\displaystyle}$
$\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}$
$\newcommand{\NN}{\mathbb{N}}$
$\newcommand{\ZZ}{\mathbb{Z}}$
$\newcommand{\brp}[1]{\left(#1\right)}$
$\newcommand{\setn}[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}$
$\newcommand{\set}[2]{\left\{#1|#2\right\}}$
$\newcommand{\linspan}{{{s\!p\!a\!n}}}$
This may not be the answer you're looking for, but some points to consider if you want $\ldots$

To avoid discontinuities when using shifted versions of B(x) as a basis,
you may want to change your definition of B(x) to
$B(x):= \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } x \in [0,\ 1) \\
0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$
(rather than $x\in[0,1]$).

The sequence $\setn{\cdots,V_n, V_{n+1}, V_{n+2},\cdots}$ is a set of nested subspaces such that
$$\ds \lim_{n\to-\infty}V_n = 0 \subset \cdots \subset V_{-2} \subset V_{-1} \subset V_0 \subset V_1 \subset V_2 \subset \cdots \subset L^2(\RR)$$
As such it would seem
$\ds L^{2}(\RR) = \lim_{n\to\infty} V_{n}$.
Note that the relation $\ds V_{n} \subset V_{n+1}$ holds for any order-$n$ B-spline, of which $B(x)$ is the special $n=0$ case.


Using the above relation, along with $V_{n+1} = W_{n} \oplus V_{n}$ yields
\begin{align*}
L^{2}(\RR) 
  &= {\lim_{n\to\infty} V_{n}}
\\&= {\lim_{n\to\infty} \brp{ W_{n-1} \oplus V_{n-1} } }
\\&= {\lim_{n\to\infty} \brp{ W_{n-1} \oplus W_{n-2} \oplus V_{n-2} } }
\\&= {\lim_{n\to\infty} \brp{ W_{n-1} \oplus W_{n-2} \oplus W_{n-3} \oplus V_{n-3} } }
\\&= {\lim_{n\to\infty} \brp{ W_{n-1} \oplus W_{n-2} \oplus W_{n-3} \oplus W_{n-4} \oplus V_{n-4} } }
\\&= {\lim_{n\to\infty} \brp{ W_{n-1} \oplus W_{n-2} \oplus W_{n-3} \oplus W_{n-4} } \oplus \cdots \oplus W_{0} \oplus V_{0} }
\\&= {\lim_{n\to\infty} \brp{ W_{n-1} \oplus W_{n-2} \oplus W_{n-3} \oplus W_{n-4} } \oplus \cdots \oplus W_{0} \oplus V_{0} }
\\&= {\lim_{n\to\infty} \brp{ W_{n-1} \oplus W_{n-2} \oplus W_{n-3} \oplus W_{n-4} } \oplus \cdots \oplus W_{0} \oplus W_{-1} \oplus V_{-1} }
\\&= {\lim_{n\to\infty} \brp{ W_{n-1} \oplus W_{n-2} \oplus W_{n-3} \oplus W_{n-4} } \oplus \cdots \oplus W_{0} \oplus W_{-1} \oplus W_{-2} \oplus V_{-2} }
\\&= {\lim_{n\to\infty} \brp{ W_{n-1} \oplus W_{n-2} \oplus W_{n-3} \oplus W_{n-4} } \oplus \cdots \oplus W_{0} \oplus W_{-1} \oplus W_{-2} \oplus\cdots\oplus\lim_{n\to-\infty} V_n }
\\&= {\lim_{n\to\infty} \brp{ W_{n-1} \oplus W_{n-2} \oplus W_{n-3} \oplus W_{n-4} } \oplus \cdots \oplus W_{0} \oplus W_{-1} \oplus W_{-2} \oplus\cdots\oplus\setn{0} }
\\&= {\bigoplus_{n\in\ZZ} W_n }
\end{align*}



Thanks for the answer. I am not really sure of how those limits are correct, but that's on me.  What is the infinite direct sum if not the limit of the partial direct sums? I just I haven't very clear the concept of limit of a sequence of subspaces. The limit of the $V_{n}'s$ is intuitively clear, I can approximate a function $f$ in $L^2$ with a sequence ${f_n}n$ with $f_n \in V^{n}.$ But a function in $\bigoplus{n \in \mathbb{Z}} W_{n}$ is a function of the form $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} f_{n}, \ f_n \in W_n$ so it can approximated by functions lying in the partial sums, right?

In addition, the fact that the limit of the sums is the sum of the limits works because we are considering orthogonal spaces, right?
